# Does yarn link follow yarn-links in dependencies?

Tags: yarnpkg

I am using yarn 1.22.10.

I am developing a project which uses a yarn-linked dependency named **module-one** which in turn yarn-links to a dependency named **module-two**.

Is yarn able to follow these yarn link chains?

Answer (score 0):

According to yarn documentation ,

> **a** package can be linked into another project.

So if **module-one** is a package which is developed using **module-two** and then **module-one** is further called into another project using yarn link, technically **it should work** provided module-one is a package containing its own *package.json*.

But I would like to suggest **not** to use **yarn link** in a chain like wise because during production if dependency **module-two** modifies/updates/returns error and these changes are not translated to **module-one**; then the project might suffer and will return with **unexpected errors/exceptions** which will be pain to track and rectify.

Therefore I would like to suggest that you must install the **module-two** as dependency in **module-one** and then yarn link **module-one** to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that my question is concerned with a development environment.

Comment: No problem Sir,                                                                                                             On a separate note, the Yarn link is generally used as a shortcut to make symlinks in your local project. Using in a chain likewise is a long complicated approach. To understand yarn link better do check out this link :https://mcocirio.medium.com/unsolving-the-mysteries-of-yarn-npm-link-for-libraries-development-41daa51a7cc6